# Calling LinkedIn REST API from server only

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

Using org.pac4j.oauth.client.LinkedIn2Client & org.pac4j.oauth.profile.linkedin2.LinkedIn2Profile java libraries v 1.5.1 on google app engine I'd like to call some of the job api's from linked in.

I've successfully created my keys and have some code based on the unit tests, however I don't understand how the oAuth flow works when it's server to server (I think term may be 2-legged) and there is no browser client and need some help.

Thanks!